# Why does this CSS code make my drop down menu show only one item of 3?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a website for my school soccer program and I'm trying to create a drop down menu with another drop down menu inside to show the "previous teams" and all of their items (roster, pictures, matches, etc.).

I've tried removing the `position: absolute` and while that makes the submenu show up, the buttons I created that should in theory expand to the actual links don't end up doing anything. When not removing the `position: absolute`, 1 item (the final item I add) shows up and I can interact with it.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="nav-link-wrapper-drops">
     <button class="Team">
       Previous Teams
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </button>

     <div class="nav-link-wrapper-down">
       <button class="button-down">
         > 2018/2019
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </button>

       <div class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
         <a href="roster1819.html">Roster</a>
         <a href="matches1819.html">Schedule</a>
         <a href="pictures1819.html">Pictures</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="nav-link-wrapper-down">
       <button class="button-down">
         > 2017/2018
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </button>

       <div class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
         <a href="roster1718.html">Roster</a>
         <a href="matches1718.html">Schedule</a>
         <a href="pictures1718.html">Pictures</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="nav-link-wrapper-down">
       <button class="button-down">
         > 2016/2017
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </button>

       <div class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
         <a href="roster1617.html">Roster</a>
         <a href="matches1617.html">Schedule</a>
         <a href="pictures1617.html">Pictures</a>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code going with this:

```
.nav-link-wrapper-drops:hover .nav-link-wrapper-down {
  display: block;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-down .button-down {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: red;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: navy;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown a {
  float: none;
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: navy;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-down:hover .nav-link-wrapper-twodown {
  display: block;
}
```

I expect the output to essentially create a "double" drop down menu where there are two levels to the drop down menu.
I'm not very familiar with HTML and I created the drop down menus with `<button>`s because of an online tutorial but on this site I've seen many people using `<li>` and `<ul>` so I'm also wondering if there IS a way to make it with `<button>`.

**EDIT:**
The inspiration for this style of navbar came from [this](https://www.mscsoccer.org/page/show/1243199-lakers) website. It's eventually what I want my website to look like - with different colors - visually.

***ALL OF MY CODE CAN BE FOUND AT [THIS](https://github.com/BlazeDaBlur1/MJHSoccer) GITHUB**.

Comment: just u want to have navbar with 2 levels of dropdown i'm right? do u want to have nav bar on which side left or top ?

Comment: @AmareshSM I want to have a navbar that drops from one spot into another drop down menu (1st goes down from top, 2nd goes to left)

Comment: And look at my new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```css
.button-down {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: red;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  height: 20px;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: navy;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown a {
  float: none;
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-drops {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.Team {
  height: 20px;
}

.Team:hover + .nav-link-wrapper-down, .nav-link-wrapper-down:hover {
 display:block;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-down {
 display:none;
  margin: 0;
}

.button-down:hover + .nav-link-wrapper-twodown, .nav-link-wrapper-twodown:hover {
 display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: right;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-link-wrapper-twodown a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: navy;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link-wrapper-drops">
  <button class="Team">
    Previous Team
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="nav-link-wrapper-down">
    <li class="item">
      <button class="button-down">
         > 2018/2019
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <ul class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
        <li><a href="roster1819.html">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="matches1819.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="pictures1819.html">Pictures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <button class="button-down second-btn">
         > 2017/2018
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <ul class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
        <li><a href="roster1718.htm">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="matches1718.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="pictures1718.html">Pictures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <button class="button-down second-btn">
         > 2016/2017
         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <ul class="nav-link-wrapper-twodown">
        <li><a href="roster1617.htm">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="matches1617.html">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="pictures1617.html">Pictures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When using this code, the position of the original buttons move with the links and/or buttons (e.g. When hovering over the 'Overview' link under the 'Team' button, the 'Team' button shifts to the left to have its right side border in line with the right side of the 'Overview' link).

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer for the code you provided, but consider refactoring your menu system to use nested lists.  Here is a dead simple prototype: https://codepen.io/JimmyJames88/pen/xvzOyg

Then it's just a matter of using css rules to show/hide the sub UL's strategically.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu item 1.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu item 1.1.1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu item 2.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu item 2.1.1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu item 3.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu item 3.1.1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
.nav > li ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This probably would work, I haven't tried it because I don't have time right now and I don't really want to refactor my code that much just yet but thank you.